# Why is Nest creating all these alarms in my Hue app?

Tags: hue, nest-api

When I connect Hue to Nest for the "works with nest" integration it creates all these alarms for each individual hue bulb, on and off all day a different times? And I can turn off the alarms but can't edit the details of them, but that seems like a pain, I have like only 7 bulbs right now but it created like 4 alarms for each for a total of 28 alarms that I have to manually go in and turn off the alarms for?? Seems ridiculous?

Comment: This seems like a question for Hue's support team. The Works With Nest API only allows Hue to talk to Nest, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Hue has pushed a fix for this issue. Please respond if you are still having issues.